# Error converting varchar to int when using convert function

Tags: sql-server

I have written a function is sql that will return either difference in days, hours or Expired. I am current getting the error . I am using the convert function to convert int to string. Not sure why it is throwing the below error. Does anybody have an idea what is wrong

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '30D' to data type int.
```

Function

```
ALTER FUNCTION declaration.GetDifferenceInDaysOrHours(@AcceptanceWindowExpiry datetime)  
RETURNS int   
AS   

BEGIN  
    DECLARE @timeDifferenceInDays INT;
    DECLARE @timeDifferenceInHours INT;
    DECLARE @timeDifference INT;
    DECLARE @result VARCHAR(100);

    SELECT @timeDifferenceInDays = DATEDIFF(d,  GETUTCDATE(), @AcceptanceWindowExpiry)  
    IF @timeDifferenceInDays > 1
      BEGIN
            SELECT @result = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @timeDifferenceInDays) + 'D'
       END
    ELSE 
     BEGIN
        SELECT @timeDifferenceInHours = DATEDIFF(HOUR,  GETUTCDATE(),  @AcceptanceWindowExpiry)  
          IF @timeDifferenceInHours >= 0 AND @timeDifferenceInHours <= 24
             BEGIN 
                SELECT @result = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @timeDifferenceInHours) + 'H'
             END
          ELSE
            BEGIN
                SELECT @result = 'EXPIRED'
          END
        END
        RETURN @result;  
    END;
```

Comment: The return type of your function.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your correctly do various string assignments to the string (varchar(100)) variable @result. However, your function returns INT:

```
ALTER FUNCTION declaration.GetDifferenceInDaysOrHours(@AcceptanceWindowExpiry datetime)  
RETURNS int   -- here's the trouble
AS
```